# sorting a dictionary based on integer value without collections.counter

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, frequency

I am trying to sort a dictionary based on the second value of the tuple for example dictionary(word_list) below may give me:

```
{'accumulative': 2, 'vacuum': 3, 'moonless': 1, 'castle': 4, 'professing': 1, 'poetry': 6}
```

Im not sure exactly how to properly sort the dictionary from highest to lowest (poetry appearing first & moonless last.

```
def dictionary(word_list):
    freq_dic = {}
    for word in word_list:
        try: 
            freq_dic[word] += 1
        except: 
            freq_dic[word] = 1
    return print(freq_dic)

dictionary(word_list)

def sort_key (dictionary(word_list)):
    return dictionary(word_list))[1]

mylist = list(dictionary(word_list).items())

sortedlist = sorted(dictionary(word_list), key = (sort_key),reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to a tuple and then proceed from there.

```
from operator import itemgetter

diction = {'accumulative': 2, 'vacuum': 3, 'moonless': 1, 'castle': 4, 'professing': 1, 'poetry': 6}
print(sorted(diction.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[('poetry', 6), ('castle', 4), ('vacuum', 3), ('accumulative', 2), ('moonless', 1), ('professing', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `def dictionary(word_list):` has a terrible bug -- it returns `print(freq_dic)` which is `None`!-)  You need to return `freq_dic`!

Once you do so, sorting by value is easy:

```
import operator
d = dictionary(word_list)
sorted_list = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: great, thank you! I kept def sort_key (d) return d[1] rather than import the operator. Is there a meathod I could use to sort the top 10 values?

Comment: To get the top 10 values, `heapq.nlargest` is best -- look it up!-)